# I'm Trying to format the output of an array using php

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, pre

I'm Trying to format the output of an array using php but I can't seem to get the keys and values on the same line. I've listed the code that I'm using to display the keys and values but this code outputs the keys and values on different lines

```
function olLiTree($tree)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            echo '<pre>', $key ;
            olLiTree($item);
            echo '</pre>';
        } else {
            echo '<pre>', $item, '</pre>'; 
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

print(olLiTree($results));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ul> <li> .... </li></ul>`. Also remove `comma(,)` because PHP use `dot(.)` for concat string.

```
function olLiTree($tree)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            echo '<li>'. $key ;
            olLiTree($item);
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li>' .$item. '</li>'; 
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

print(olLiTree($results));
```

Answer (score 0):

You use comma `,` instead of dot `.` 
for string concatenation php use dot

```
    function olLiTree($tree)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            echo '<pre>'. $key ;
            olLiTree($item);
            echo '</pre>';
        } else {
            echo '<pre>' . $item. '</pre>'; 
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

print(olLiTree($results));
```